# How we accessed wait() non-static method of object class without instantiating the class?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
class TestJoinMethod1 extends Thread{  
 public void run(){  
  for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){  
   try{  
    Thread.sleep(500);  
   }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}  
  System.out.println(i);  
  }  
 }  
public static void main(String args[]){  
 TestJoinMethod1 t1=new TestJoinMethod1();  
 TestJoinMethod1 t2=new TestJoinMethod1();  
 TestJoinMethod1 t3=new TestJoinMethod1();  
 t1.start();  
 try{  
  t1.join();  
 }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}  

 t2.start();  
 t3.start();  
 }  
}
```

The `join` method belongs to a non-static method of thread class. Here they create an object of the class which extends thread and using that reference variable they access the `join` method.

```
public class Account 
{
   int bal=5000;
   synchronized public  void withdraw(int amt)
   {
       System.out.println("balance is="+bal);
       if(amt>bal)
       {
           System.out.println("low balance waiting for deposit");
           try
           {
               wait(5000);
               bal=bal-amt;
               System.out.println("override balance ="+bal);
          }
           catch (InterruptedException  e)
           {
              e.printStackTrace(); 
           }
       }

   }
    synchronized  public   void deposit(int amt)
       {
           System.out.println("depositing"+amt);
           bal=bal+amt;
           System.out.println("available bal="+bal);
           notify();
          }

}
```

How do we access the non-static method of object class without creating the object? The `wait` method and `notify` method. Normally for non-static methods, we create an object and using that we invoke. But for this, how do we access without creating an object?

Comment: You don't. Why do you think you would need to? The whole point of `wait` and `notify` is that you have something shared (the object) to communicate through.

Comment: It makes no sense to call a non-static method of a class without instantiating a member of the class.  The whole point of non-static methods is that they do something to or with a member of the class.

Comment: You won't be able to access the non static methods `withdraw` or `deposit` either. If however you have an instance of `Account` then you can access these methods, aswell as `wait` and `notifiy` both of which `Account` inherits from `java.lang.Object`

Comment: Your question makes no sense. `wait()` causes the current thread to wait until the object it was called on is notified. No object, no notification, so even if it was possible it would just wait forever. You need to read the documentation.

Comment: And as a matter of fact this code already compiles, and already has access to the *inherited* `wait()` and `notify()` methods. You don't need another object, or static access. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: And why you are using a timed wait is another mystery. Why should the withdrawal become legal just because five seconds elapsed?

Comment: @EJP, I think he simply confused `wait()` and `sleep()`.

Answer (score 2):

Every non-static method has an explicit reference (`this`) to the object on which this method was called. So `notify()` is the same as `this.notify()` where `this` is the `Account` variable on which `deposit()` is called. So there is no problem here to solve.

Comment: I am asking  how we used wait() and notify() method in multithreading without the creation of object we invoked nonstatic method of object class.

Comment: The question is how to call non-static method using `this`? Or how to use `wait/notify` for concurrency?

Comment: As I've said in the answer `notify()` will be called on the same object of `Account` class on which `deposit` is called. And `wait` will be called on the object of `Account` class on which `withdraw` is called